# how to make my python code do a task after specific time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

im using raspberry pi and raspberry pi camera to make a project .. the project is basically glasses that can record videos and take pictures using an IR sensor and I went with TCRT5000 ... What I want to do exactly is when the sensor reads low value nothing happens and when it reads high and the the time since it read high is for 2 seconds it takes a picture and when the time its been high for more than 3 seconds it records a video...

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep
import time

camera = PiCamera()
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN)


while True:
      sensor=GPIO.input(18)
      if sensor==1 and :
         sleep(2)
            camera.capture("/home/pi/Desktop/Project/Pictures/image%s.jpg")
            print("I TOOK A PICTURE ")
            sleep(2)
            print(" IM RECORDING A VIDEO !!!")

        camera.start_recording('/home/pi/Desktop/Project/Videos/video.h264')
            camera.stop_recording()
            sleep(10)
                print("NOTHING")
                sleep(1)
      elif sensor==0 :
            print("NOTHING")
                sleep(1)
```

this is the code im going with for the moment can anyone help me ?

Comment: Use the dedicated tools for task management as `cronjob`

Comment: im new in python really can you explain more to me?

Comment: I can't, but if you google `setting up cron jobs` you will find a lot of inormation. If you are stuck with something, you can ask a question. On Stackoverflow, people expect you to do a initial research and attempt.

Comment: I have already done a research and thats not what i want to do .. I don't wants to schedule a task I want my code to start passed on an if statement

Comment: And what part of your code doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as your while True block

```
#Declare oldTime variable, but it is blank.
oldTime = ""

while True:
    sensor=GPIO.input(18)

    if sensor==1:
        if(time.time() - oldTime == 2):
            camera.capture("/home/pi/Desktop/Project/Pictures/image%s.jpg")
            print("I TOOK A PICTURE ")
        if(time.time() - oldTime == 3):
            print(" IM RECORDING A VIDEO !!!")
            camera.start_recording('/home/pi/Desktop/Project/Videos/video.h264')
            sleep(10)
            camera.stop_recording()
            print(" I HAVE STOPPED RECORDING!!! ")
    elif sensor==0:
        oldTime = time.time()
```

The script is constantly checking the time whenever the button is not pushed and storing it in `oldTime` as soon as the button becomes pushed, it starts checking if the time difference between now and `oldTime` is equal to '2' or '3' and then performs the appropriate action.

You might have to do some rounding to get it to equal 2 or 3.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help .. but the code keeps on giving me that oldTime is not defined and im using python3

Comment: So, declare it before the while loop. (Answer amended)

Comment: I already done that and everything works fine thanks so much for the help